# Python - Code keeps returning an unwanted "None" statement

Tags: python

My code below is returning an unwanted "None" statement. I have searched other questions in hopes to find a solution but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def int_mult(no1,no2):
    try:
        no3 = int(no1)
        no3 = int(no2)
    except ValueError:
        return print("Error: Invalid Argument Type")
    no1 = int(round(no1))
    no2 = int(round(no2))
    return (no1 * no2)



print (int_mult(4.49,"apple"))
```

Comment: What do you want it to return?
It does *exactly* what it should, because `print` returns None. Do you want to stop it from printing the returned value if it fails?

Comment: If it hits the "Error: Invalid Argument Type" I don't want it to also print "None" as well. Which is what it is doing. Is there a way to do that without altering the print statement and only working on what is inside the function?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way is to actually raise an exception.

```python
def int_mult(no1, no2):
    try:
        return int(no1) * int(no2)
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError("Invalid Argument Type")


try:
    print(int_mult_(4.49, "apple"))
except TypeError as e:
    print(", ".join(e.args))
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this by just altering what is within the function and not with the print statement as well?

Comment: Then you would replace the `raise TypeError("Invalid Argument Type")` with `return "Invalid Argument Type"`. But this is *not* a good style of coding, you should keep the values returned consistent (in a way that a certain set of types given to it will return the same type every time, no matter the value, or raise an exception).

Answer (score 1):

in line 5 you say:

`return print("Error: Invalid Argument Type")`

This doesn't tell python to return the string IN the print function.
Instead this tells python to return the  print function.

Probably this will make it clearer:

In your last line you wrote:

```
print (int_mult(4.49,"apple"))
```

So first python runs the int_mult() function and the function returns

```
print("Error: Invalid Argument Type")
```

then python prints, like you ordered in your last line, exactly what your Int_mult() function returned. For python it looks like this:

```
print ( print("Error: Invalid Argument Type") )
```

In this line Python runs first the function `print("Error: Invalid Argument Type")` and prints the string. After that python runs **print(** print("Error: Invalid Argument Type") **)**  and prints the print function what will return `None` or something like `<function house at 0x7f494763abf8>`.

If i was you i would just change line 5 to

```
return ("Error: Invalid Argument Type")
```

and your last line to

```
print (int_mult(4.49,"android"))
```

;)

I hope that I have helped you.